# Find which ranges in a set that has a nonempty intersection with some specified range

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Let us have a set of ranges r1, r2, ... rn. Then choose some other range R. What is the fastest (or at least a fast) algorithm to determine which of the ranges r1, r2, ... rn that has a nonempty intersection with R? Is there an optimal datastructure to store the set of ranges in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) is the way to go.